# go-redis library's SMembers method returning extra element in first position

Tags: go, go-redis

I'm using the go-redis library v9, and wrote a simple test case using miniredis.

In a simple case, I use go-redis SAdd to add an item to a set, then use SMembers to get all the items back.

For some reason, SMembers is returning an extra numeric item in the beginning of the string slice.

```
added := redis.SAdd(ctx, "key1", "android_device2", expiration)
members := redis.SMembers(ctx, "key1").Val()
fmt.Printf("%v", members)
```

This prints `[2592000000000000 android_device2]`, where could that first numeric element be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [the function signature](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/redis/go-redis/v9#Client.SAdd), `SAdd` takes the context, the key, and then a list of members to add. You've added two members, the `"android_device2"` string, and whatever `expiration` is. When you pull the set members you're seeing those two.

Comment: Agh, it was supposed to be the key expiration. Thanks for spotting the silly mistake.